# Show Post from parent category (custom taxonomy) ONLY!

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I want to display all post under a parent category (custom taxonomy) ONLY!.

Here's what I've done so far:'

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => 100, 
'post_status'   => 'publish', 
'tax_query'     => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'ait-dir-item-category',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => 75
    )
), 
'post_type'     => 'ait-dir-item' );
$the_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

This displays all the posts including the sub categories, which I don't want to.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `tax_query` can take an `include_children` argument (see Codex) that defaults to `true`. So just add that to your code and it should work:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => 100, 
'post_status'   => 'publish', 
'tax_query'     => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'ait-dir-item-category',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => 75,
        'include_children' => false
    )
), 
'post_type'     => 'ait-dir-item' );
$the_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

*Note: I'm unsure of the behavior of `include_children` when a post is assigned to both a child and parent, but I would guess that the post would show up.*

---

EDIT: Posted the wrong link earlier. from [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

> **include_children** *(boolean)* - Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.

Comment: Just wondering why this doesn't appear on the wordpress documentation? Is it already up since 3.2 ? BDW. This is the right answer..

Comment: See edit. It is documented.